# How to set path to python interpreter virtualenv with uwsgi

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm working through https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04.

In it they advise testing uwsgi with the following:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/sammy/Env/firstsite --chdir /home/sammy/firstsite -w firstsite.wsgi
```

I'm using the more recent 2.12 version of uWSGI and the options have changed. I'm looking through http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io .My virtual app is called myapp3 and is at/Env/myapp3. So far I have:

```
$ uwsgi --http-socket :8080 --venv /home/deploy/Env/myapp3 --chdir /home/deploy/myapp3 --wsgi myapp.wsgi
```

I get:

```
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--venv'
getopt_long() error
```

Comment: so how did you come up to the `--venv` parameter? The only thing I can see in docs is `--virtualenv`

Comment: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#venv . BTW, getting the same error with --virtualenv

Comment: From the docs, it seems that `-H`, `--pyhome`, `--home`, `--venv`, and `--virtualenv` are aliases of each other.

Comment: BTW: There's no version 2.12 of uwsgi. The latest version is 2.0.14. Are you sure you are not using the older 2.0.12 ?

Comment: Sorry , yes, 2.0.12

Answer (score 1):

Try with `-H` option

```
uwsgi --http-socket :8080 -H /home/deploy/Env/myapp3 --chdir /home/deploy/myapp3 --wsgi myapp.wsgi
```

Comment: is '-H' for passing path python interpreter, not working for me?